# Are ancient Greek stories a key to unlock large sections of MacDonald’s ‘At the Back of the North Wind’?

Tags: greek-myth, george-macdonald

In the first paragraph of MacDonald’s *At the Back of the North Wind,* the autor introduces the reader to an “old Greek writer,” as well as other important parts of his book and its enigmatic title:

> I have been asked  to tell you about the back of the North Wind. An old Greek writer mentions a people who lived there, and were so comfortable that they could not bear it any longer, and drowned themselves.

In the next sentence, MacDonald tells us that the old Greek writer he has in mind is Herodotus. Are these references to Herodotus and his stories about people who lived at the back of the North Wind MacDonald’s clues for a better understanding of his book?

Answer (score -6):

An understanding of what Herodotus wrote is key to much that is enigmatic in and about MacDonald’s book and its strange title.  Herodotus wrote about the Hyperboreans, or “those at the back of the North Wind,” in his *Histories* (Book IV, Chapters 32–36). The ancient Greek North Wind was the god Boreas, who shares much in common with MacDonald’s North Wind, a type of powerful, airy, deity.

The Hyperboreans, as MacDonald implies, were conceived of as an almost perfect people, living in an almost perfect place:

> Hyperborean, in Greek religion, one of a mythical people intimately connected with the worship of Apollo at Delphi and of Artemis at Delos. The Hyperboreans were named with reference to Boreas, the north wind, and their home was placed in a paradisal region in the far north, “beyond the north wind.” They lived for 1,000 years; if any desired to shorten that period, he decked himself with garlands and threw himself from a rock into the sea.

-[Hyperboreans, Britanica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Hyperborean)

Comment: Nice, but I don't see that you've answered your own question.  It's clear that those are the people MacDonald is talking about in his introduction, but how does that "unlock large parts of the book"?

Comment: Almost every thing  todo with GM’s North Wind can be better understood through Boreas, the Greek north wind.  Many times Boreas was pictured as a horse in Greek myths, thus helping to explain much of the horse material, especially as it relates to GM’s North Wind, in the book. The place “at the back of the North Wind” then  can be better understood through the lens of Hyperborea.

Comment: OK, then that should be in your answer, otherwise it's, well, not an answer to the question.